# How do I customize Pry's .pryrc file?

Tags: ruby, macos, irb, pry

I'm trying to customize pry's `pryrc` file, but I can't find it.  The docs say that it's in the home directory, but I don't see it in there. If it's invisible, can tell me how to edit it despite that fact?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pry only reads the `~/.pryrc` file if it exists, if it doesn't exist (as in your case) you can just create it.

Comment: You accepted an answer from someone who said the same thing as me? After I answered your ridiculous questions 4 times?

Comment: When pry starts, it checks for a pryrc file in` $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/pry/pryrc` or in your home directory (~/.pryrc), and also for a per-project .pryrc in the current directory(./.pryrc). Both files are used if they exist, with the file from your home directory being loaded first. "From the pry/wiki"

Comment: From the docs: A pryrc file in $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/pry/ or the user's home directory will be loaded if it exists.  If you don't know what `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is, you're probably not using it.   `touch ~/.pryrc && nano ~/.pryrc`.

Answer (score 6):

Did you try `ls .pryrc`? If it's not there, just put it there.

Comment: it's not there, but (this may be a stupid remark) I don't know how to put it there if I can't find it.

Comment: Either `touch .pryrc` or use an editor and save a file there as .pryrc

Comment: but won't it conflict with other .pryrc files?

Comment: There can only be one file called .pryrc in your home folder. That's the one pry reads.

Comment: touch .pryrc "Operation is not supported".  When I try to create .pryrc with Sublime, it says it can't create it

Comment: Sublime Text 2.  Using Mac, snow leopard

Comment: It sounds like a permissions problem. This is a mac question at this point and probably belongs at superuser.com